# Getting original request url in case of proxy routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, proxy, http-proxy

I have to generate a URL during a request. This URL has to lead to the application itself with an absolute path (link in an email to the calling user).
Now I have the problem that in some cases the application is running in envirements where different proxies are used. Different users can only access one of this proxies but not the appliaction itself. So I have to use the URL that was send to the proxy, not the URL that was used by the proxy to call the application.

Currently I used HttpRequest.Current to build the URL.
There the wrong URL is delivered in this cases.

Is there any property in the .net classes or standard for proxies (HTTP-Headers, ...) to preserve the original URL?

Comment: The proxy should not be changing the URL.  If proxies changed URLs all the time they would not be useful.  Have you double checked how you are making the request to the proxy in the first place?

Comment: I have created a test setup to check whats happening with the requests and there the URL is changed...
Maybe the used proxy is not well implemented... but I have to handle this situation.
(I'm talking about the URL that the application recives, not the one in browser)

Comment: in what way is the URL changed?

Comment: If the proxy is using rules to rewrite requests, it would need to also attach the original URL somehow for that to remain available at the target server.  But don't get misled by the proxy taking a fully-qualified URL (including scheme and authority)and making an upstream request containing only the path/resource.  The host header plus the scheme used plus the resource requested should still be the same URL.  To illustrate this point, the client if not using a proxy should make the same request that the proxy would on its behalf.

Comment: The Proxy gets called with "url1" and redirects the request to the application with "url2". In the HttpRequest.Current object only "url2" is used. I also could not find any header or something like that.

Maybe this is just because of the proxy or its configuration in our test environment, but as long this is can happen, I must be able to handle this situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I'm using a solution thats not realy nice but working:
I'm using the login to the application to request the client url (login request sends the client url) and store this information in the user session. So i can use it to generate the needed URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There's unfortunately nothing "standard" in net, if in your `Host` it reads the wrong url then the only option is to add a header to your proxy to pass to your app. In case of nginx I used something like in the conf file:

```
location /couch/api/ {
        proxy_pass         https://0.0.0.0:5030;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
 
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;  
        
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host; # <-- this is the saver!
    }
```

result headers received by app:

```
Host : 0.0.0.0:5040 <--- okay this is wrong.. it's behind proxy
X-Forwarded-For : 180.291.138.555 
X-Forwarded-Proto : https 
X-Forwarded-Host : mysupadomain.com <--- success =)
```